# Startup script to run in background

Tags: windows, powershell, command-line, batch-file

I have the following bat file:

```
@echo off
start /min powershell "& 'C:\Admin\c.ps1'"
exit
```

I don't want to display the powershell window as this is an administrative script that runs on startup.

I was under the impression that using `start /min` will solve it, but It's still displaying.

Answer (score 3):

PowrShell has a switch to launch itself hideen. That said, the console may be visible for a short period of time until it disappears. Since this is an administrative script, I would also recommend using the NonInteractive switch to prevent someone from interfering with it

```
@echo off
powershell -NonInteractive -File C:\Admin\c.ps1 
exit
```

If you can't afford the console to be visible at all, consider using a vbs file to launch powershell:

```
Set oShell = CreateObject("WSCript.Shell")
oShell.Run("powershell -NonInteractive -File C:\Admin\c.ps1",0,False)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use 'Task Scheduler', 'Run Once On Startup', there is an option to hide windows like this.

Answer (score 1):

`START` command has option `/b` to start an application without creating a new window.

try

```
start /b powershell "& 'C:\Admin\c.ps1'"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a VBScript to stop the window from appearing at all.

```
Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
objShell.Run("C:\Admin\c.ps1"), 0, True
```

Plus you can use this instead of the batch file, so there will be no cmd window either.

Hope this helps.